# Authenticate SSRS 2016 from an iframe

Tags: iframe, reporting-services

I made up an iframe pointing to SSRS 2016, but every time the browser shows me a window to authenticate.

Is there a way to pass credentials to the server in order to authenticate and not showing the login window to the user?

Comment: I have the same issue - have you resolved the issue

Comment: Unfortunately not. We tried different solutions but none of them resolved this issue

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, was really frustrated about it. I found a '**dirty**' workaround by creating a rudimentary API in PHP that handles the authentication for me.

If you want to try this route, do this:
Have a look at this page, and install this package in your PHP (it wasn't updated since 2010 but it still works fine): https://ssrsphp.codeplex.com/

Here is the example from the page (useful if you want to pass parameters to your report):

```
    // include the SSRS library
require_once 'SSRSReport.php';

define("REPORT", "/AdventureWorks 2008 Sample Reports/TopStoresBegin");
$settings = parse_ini_file("app.config", 1);
// Create a connection to the SSRS Server
$rs = new SSRSReport(new Credentials($settings["UID"], $settings["PASWD"]),$settings["SERVICE_URL"]);

// Load the report and specify the params required for its execution
$executionInfo = $rs->LoadReport2(REPORT, NULL);
$parameters = array();
$parameters[0] = new ParameterValue();
$parameters[0]->Name = "ProductCategory";
$parameters[0]->Value = "1";
$parameters[1] = new ParameterValue();
$parameters[1]->Name = "StartDate";
$parameters[1]->Value = "1/1/2003";
$parameters[2] = new ParameterValue();
$parameters[2]->Name = "EndDate";
$parameters[2]->Value = "12/31/2003";
$parameters[3] = new ParameterValue();
$parameters[3]->Name = "ProductSubcategory";
$parameters[3]->Value = "2";
$rs->SetExecutionParameters2($parameters);

// Require the Report to be rendered in HTML format
$renderAsHTML = new RenderAsHTML();

// Set the links in the reports to point to the php app

$renderAsHTML->ReplacementRoot = getPageURL();

// Set the root path on the server for any image included in the report
$renderAsHTML->StreamRoot = './images/';

// Execute the Report
$result_html = $rs->Render2($renderAsHTML,
                                 PageCountModeEnum::$Actual,
                                 $Extension,
                                 $MimeType,
                                 $Encoding,
                                 $Warnings,
                                 $StreamIds);

// Save all images on the server (under /images/ dir)
    foreach($StreamIds as $StreamId)
    {
        $renderAsHTML->StreamRoot = null;
        $result_png = $rs->RenderStream($renderAsHTML,
                                    $StreamId,
                                    $Encoding,
                                    $MimeType);

        if (!$handle = fopen("./images/" . $StreamId, 'wb'))
        {
            echo "Cannot open file for writing output";
            exit;
        }

        if (fwrite($handle, $result_png) === FALSE)
        {
            echo "Cannot write to file";
            exit;
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
// include the Report within a Div on the page
echo '<html><body><br/><br/>';
echo '<div align="center">';
echo '<div style="overflow:auto; width:700px; height:600px">';
    echo $result_html;
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</body></html>';
```

However for my needs I have simplified the code very much. Also I had to remove the url rewrite function from it as it would mess up server session id, and that in turn would mean that if you had any drilldowns on your reports they would not work at all. This is snippet from my code:

```
/* Load SSRS Library */
require_once 'SSRSReport.php';

/* Load a report - remember that you can set up an external file that would hold the login credentials for you, I left those here for demonstration only*/
            define("UID", 'Your user name here'); 
            define("PWD", "Your pass"); 
            define("SERVICE_URL", "Service url for your ssrs"); 
            define("REPORT", "Variable with your 'path to' and name of report");
        try
        {
            $ssrs_report = new SSRSReport(new Credentials(UID, PWD),
                                         SERVICE_URL);
            $ssrs_report->LoadReport2(REPORT, NULL);

            $htmlFormat = new RenderAsHTML();
            $htmlFormat->StreamRoot = './images/';
            $result_html = $ssrs_report->Render2($htmlFormat,
                                        PageCountModeEnum::$Estimate,
                                        $Extension,
                                        $MimeType,
                                        $Encoding,
                                        $Warnings,
                                        $StreamIds);
            echo $result_html;
        }
        Catch(SSRSReportException $serviceExcprion)
        {
            echo $serviceExcprion->GetErrorMessage();
        }
```

So in my app when I make the call to my api I pass the name of the report and the  path (url encoded) at the end of the url. Then I decode it on the server, PHP SSRS SDK then logs you in grabs the report and returns it as HTML (works a charm for PDF or CSV too)

So in an iFrame I put the url for my api with the parameter at the end. You can obviously handle any extra parameters this way. Then when I go to my main app I no longer see login screen and the report displays immediately.

One problem I've found though is that still, very very occasionally you do get logged out somehow and the dreaded login screen shows itself, but then on the page refresh it works again.

Hope this helps!